# Excel Save As CSV: which one for R

Tags: r

A question from a noob R user ... when I save Excel as CSV, there are 4 options:
 1. CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)
 2. CSV (Comma delimited)
 3. CSV (Macintosh)
 4. CSV (MS-DOS)

[Excel Save As options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSJnL.png)

I am using a PC so I suppose I should choose between the first and the second options. What are the difference and which one best suits R?

System Information
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.12730.20188) 64-bit

Best,
H.

Comment: The easiest is to try it out. I would try CSV (Comma delimited) if you have **no** international characters (e.g. accents) or CSV (UTF-8) otherwise.

Comment: @tpetzoldt Agree but I would try CSV (UTF-8) first.

Comment: Thanks! International characters require UTF-8 noted. As I have worked with Visual Basic for a while intuitively I am cautious about choosing file types, particularly at the beginning of a project. As the workflow, once created, will be shared with the team, and it can be difficult to switch components later on. That's why I am keen to learn more about this.